# jQuery prev to hide one div and display another after clicking link

Tags: jquery, html

Please forgive the noob-ness of this question. I've been hacking around for days trying to make this work!

Please check out my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3cbZ/5/) here.

Basically I'm trying to design a product view page where if you click on a thumbnail image, a larger image (and info) is displayed to the right of the page. The repeated code is dynamically generated with php.

I've tried using the 'prev' selector, but it doesn't seem to work unless the div I want to display is in the same containing div as the link (which doesn't display the bigger image correctly). I tried prevAll, but that didn't work either.. really stuck now! The link is nested within two div's which I have mocked up in the fiddle example, as I'm thinking that this would have a bearing on things.

**HTML**

```
<div class="big_pic">
    <p>product 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showContent(this)">Click for product 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="big_pic">
  <p>product 2</p>
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="showContent(this)">Click for product 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.big_pic {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

Dodgy jQuerying:

```
function showContent(e) {
  $('.big_pic').hide('fast');
  $(e).prev('div.big_pic').show('slow');
}
```

The idea behind the function is that all previously displayed divs are cleared before the new one is displayed.

Thanks in advance for any light anyone can shed for me!!

Answer (score 1):

`prev` only selects the previous sibling element of the selected element, you can use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method for selecting the grandparent of the `a` element which is sibling of the target element and then `prev` method.

```
function showContent(e) {
  $('.big_pic').hide('fast');
  $(e).closest('.div1').prev('div.big_pic').show('slow');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yP4cz/

Comment: lol, I made a fiddle with just about the same code, came back to post, and noticed you beat me to it by a few seconds :P +1

Comment: Yay! You guys are awesome!  Knew it had to be something simple!

Answer (score 0):

`prev()` selects the previous sibling, so to select the 'big_pic' as a sibling, you first need to get to the corresponding 'div1'.

Since `e` represents the link, you can use `.parents()` to do just this to get a hold of its containing 'div1', and then from there use `prev()` to get the corresponding 'big_pic'. E.g:

```
$(e).parents('div.div1').prev('div.big_pic').show('slow');
```

Comment: Thanks very much or your reply. That helps my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this without the onclick in html:

```
$(function(){
  $('.div2 a').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.div1').prev('.big_pic').show('slow');
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x3cbZ/7/

Comment: Cheers.. Is it better practice to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in saying that the 'big_pic' div will only show if its in the same div as the link. Thats how prev works. It's going to the previous sibling.

What you want is to move up the DOM with .parent(). So the javascript that I got working with your HTML looked like this:

```
function showContent(e) {
  $('.big_pic').hide('fast');
  $(e).parent().parent().prev('div.big_pic').show('slow');
}
```